# Why hashing mapped vector is slower than pushed one?

Tags: rust, optimization

compiler: `rustc 1.74.1 (a28077b28 2023-12-04)`
command: `cargo run --release`

Summary:
Hashing a vector created by `.iter().map(..).collect()` is about ten times slower than one created by `for .. { v.push(..); }`

```rust
// Slow
let valve_states: Vec<bool> = valves.iter().map(|valve| valve.rate == 0).collect();
```

```rust
// Fast
let mut valve_states = Vec::with_capacity(valves.len());
for valve in valves {
    valve_states.push(valve.rate == 0);
}
```

Context:
I'm working on [Advent of Code 2022 Day 16 part one](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/16). For caching, I'm using a `HashMap` with `State` as a key. A `State` contains a `valve_states: Vec<bool>` representing the open state of valves. Valves with zero rate are initially considered open.

When I create `valve_states` with `map` and `collect`, it takes about 30% more time than using push. I profiled with `profile-bpfcc` and found that hashing is slow. More specifically, the function `_$LT$core..hash..sip..Hasher$LT$S$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..hash..Hasher$GT$::write::hbafe4103b29dec41`(maybe `core::hash::sip::Hasher<S> as core::hash::Hasher>::write`) was sampled ten times more frequently.

Question:
Why is this happening? Both approaches have the same length and capacity(len == 62, cap == 62), and `State::new` is called only once, so other hashed states are cloned.

For more details, you can find the full source code and flamegraph [here](https://gist.github.com/asd142513/d3c7dc7d15ffdf46a5cccae0de0377b0#file-main-rs-L49).

Comment: What are the actual times? 62 `bool`s is pretty tiny, so there's a possibility that the difference is noise. If not, I would suspect inlining is the culprit -- you should be able to tell by creating the `Vec` inside `std::hint::black_box()` and rerunning both methods.

Comment: @MacO'Brien On my laptop, the runtime is approximately 34s vs. 45s. On the desktop, it's around 11s vs. 20s.
The laptop runs i5-8250U, the desktop runs i7-14700K

Comment: @MacO'Brien Replacing `valves` with `black_box(valves)` did not impact the results. I believe the `valves` are inherently in a black box state as they are parsed from a file.

In essence, the concern here is not about the map-collect being slower than push, but rather the observed slowness in cloning and hashing operations.

Comment: What if you `black_box` between filling the `Vec` and the hashing?

Comment: @PitaJ `cache.insert(current_state.clone(), (remaining_time, total))` ->
`cache.insert(black_box(black_box(current_state).clone()), (remaining_time, total))`
Same result, too.

Comment: I meant something like `let valve_states = black_box(valve_states)`

Comment: @PitaJ https://gist.github.com/asd142513/2409db24028a9db50391e1ce9f49b855 Is this what you meant? It didn't have any impact.

Comment: No idea why this would be. Figuring it out will probably require diving into assembly.

Comment: On my computer, `map()`+`collect()` and `push()` give similar durations and flamegraphs.

Comment: @prog-fh Did you use same code and input? Could you share your flamegraphs?

Comment: @DonghyeonLee Yes, I used the code and input from your link. [Here are](https://file.io/ymBWaaeqJtTM) the flamegraphs and the trace.

Comment: @prog-fh It seems that the `codegen-units = 1` option eliminates the difference between the two methods. This option slows down the push case.

Comment: @DonghyeonLee It's even stranger... It's supposed to help [get better performances](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#codegen-units), but it's not the case...